# looping on column values for capturing non-zero values

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a small for loop in R that is troubling me.
My data has the following structure ( with thousands of records):

```
       City  Street    Time  Name Value
1  New York Street1  Week 1  John     0
2  New York Street1  Week 2  John     0
3  New York Street1  Week 3 James     0
4  New York Street1  Week 3 James     5
5  New York Street2  Week 4  Kate     0
6  New York Street2  Week 4  Kate     3
7  New York Street4  Week 7  Kate     0
8  New York Street4  Week 8  Kate     0
9  New York Street4  Week 9  John     0
10   Boston Street1  Week 1 James     0
11   Boston Street1  Week 2 James     0
12   Boston Street1  Week 3  John     0
13   Boston Street1  Week 4  Kate     0
14   Boston Street1  Week 5  John     0
15   Boston Street1  Week 6  Kate     0
16   Boston Street1  Week 7  Kate     0
17   Boston Street1  Week 8 James     0
18   Boston Street1  Week 9 James     0
19   Boston Street1 Week 10  Kate     2
20   Boston Street5 Week 11  John     0
21   Boston Street5 Week 12  Kate     3
22   Boston Street5 Week 13  Kate     0
```

I am trying to find the first week with a non-zero value in every city/street combination, then delete all names before this occurrence for that specific city/street combination and moving on to the next city/street combination.

I am thinking my output should look like this.

```
       City  Street    Time  Name Value
1  New York Street1  Week 1     -     0
2  New York Street1  Week 2     -     0
3  New York Street1  Week 3     -     0
4  New York Street1  Week 3 James     5
5  New York Street2  Week 4     -     0
6  New York Street2  Week 4  Kate     3
7  New York Street4  Week 7  Kate     0
8  New York Street4  Week 8  Kate     0
9  New York Street4  Week 9  John     0
10   Boston Street1  Week 1     -     0
11   Boston Street1  Week 2     -     0
12   Boston Street1  Week 3     -     0
13   Boston Street1  Week 4     -     0
14   Boston Street1  Week 5     -     0
15   Boston Street1  Week 6     -     0
16   Boston Street1  Week 7     -     0
17   Boston Street1  Week 8     -     0
18   Boston Street1  Week 9     -     0
19   Boston Street1 Week 10  Kate     2
20   Boston Street5 Week 11     -     0
21   Boston Street5 Week 12  Kate     3
22   Boston Street5 Week 13  Kate     0
```

I have tried a simple for loop but it is looping over row numbers no city/street names.

Can you please help?

**Data**

```
 my_data <- 
structure(list(City = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Boston", 
"New York"), class = "factor"), Street = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Street1", "Street2", "Street4", 
"Street5"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Week 1", "Week 10", "Week 11", 
"Week 12", "Week 13", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5", 
"Week 6", "Week 7", "Week 8", "Week 9"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("James", "John", "Kate"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))

    expected_output <- 
structure(list(City = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Boston", 
"New York"), class = "factor"), Street = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Street1", "Street2", "Street4", 
"Street5"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Week 1", "Week 10", "Week 11", 
"Week 12", "Week 13", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5", 
"Week 6", "Week 7", "Week 8", "Week 9"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("James", "John", "Kate"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Comment: because the condition of finding the a non-zero value was not achieved, for this specific city/street combination

Comment: My bad. Row number 4 should have been street 1. I am editing the input/output files.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I caused. I think the last row should stay the same, similar to row 8.

Comment: akrun, imagine this as a for loop. Once the city/street combination non-zero value is found, the "next for" jumps to the next city/street combination. Therefore, Boston street 5 non zero value was found at 21. The loop exits this city/street combination, leaving row 22 as "Kate".

Comment: Thanks, can you please check the updated solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table`, this could be done by converting the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(my_data)`), convert the 'Name' to `character` class (if it is needed as `factor`, then we need to specify `-` as one of the `levels` of the 'Name' before the assignment).  Grouped by 'City', 'Street', get the row index where (`Value == 0`) `if` there is `any` 'Value' that is not a zero in that group, get the row index (`.I`) of the the cumulative sum of logical vector (`Value != 0`) that is less than 1 and assign 'Name' to '-' for those rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)[, Name := as.character(Name)]
i1 <-  my_data[, if(any(Value !=0)) .I[cumsum(Value !=0) < 1] , 
                  .(City, Street)]$V1
my_data[i1, Name := '-']
#         City  Street    Time  Name Value
# 1: New York Street1  Week 1     -     0
# 2: New York Street1  Week 2     -     0
# 3: New York Street1  Week 3     -     0
# 4: New York Street1  Week 3 James     5
# 5: New York Street2  Week 4     -     0
# 6: New York Street2  Week 4  Kate     3
# 7: New York Street4  Week 7  Kate     0
# 8: New York Street4  Week 8  Kate     0
# 9: New York Street4  Week 9  John     0
#10:   Boston Street1  Week 1     -     0
#11:   Boston Street1  Week 2     -     0
#12:   Boston Street1  Week 3     -     0
#13:   Boston Street1  Week 4     -     0
#14:   Boston Street1  Week 5     -     0
#15:   Boston Street1  Week 6     -     0
#16:   Boston Street1  Week 7     -     0
#17:   Boston Street1  Week 8     -     0
#18:   Boston Street1  Week 9     -     0
#19:   Boston Street1 Week 10  Kate     2
#20:   Boston Street5 Week 11     -     0
#21:   Boston Street5 Week 12  Kate     3
#22:   Boston Street5 Week 13  Kate     0
```

---

A similar option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data %>% 
    mutate(Name = as.character(Name)) %>% 
    group_by(City, Street) %>% 
    mutate(Name = if(any(Value!=0)) 
            replace(Name, cumsum(Value != 0) < 1, '-') else Name)
# A tibble: 22 x 5
# Groups:   City, Street [5]
#   City     Street  Time   Name  Value
#   <fct>    <fct>   <fct>  <chr> <int>
# 1 New York Street1 Week 1 -         0
# 2 New York Street1 Week 2 -         0
# 3 New York Street1 Week 3 -         0
# 4 New York Street1 Week 3 James     5
# 5 New York Street2 Week 4 -         0
# 6 New York Street2 Week 4 Kate      3
# 7 New York Street4 Week 7 Kate      0
# 8 New York Street4 Week 8 Kate      0
# 9 New York Street4 Week 9 John      0
#10 Boston   Street1 Week 1 -         0
# ... with 12 more rows
```

Comment: thank you for the response and for avoiding the for loop :) The output from your one-liner is close to what I am aiming at but not exaclty, as the code above omits names for any given zero value. Please see my sample output. I am trying to delete the names associated with zero values UNTIL the first Non-zero value is met in a given city/street combination.

Comment: @Learner123  I have some confusion based on your logic.  Based on the input data, the first 3 rows, Name values are changed to '-' because there are no non-zero values in 'Value' for 'New York Street1'  But, why is Name 7-9 not changed to '-' for the combination 'New York Street 4'.  Those rows also have 0 Value'

Comment: Thank you for the help @akrun. Working like a charm. No for loops needed indeed. :)